# Fortran, knowing the array index, but still has error. segmentation fault - invalid memory reference

Tags: memory, reference, fortran

I have an array at%mag(:,i).

`call print('this is postion==========='//at%mag(:,i))` prints the value: 0.10069999999999999E+001 0.18200000000000001E+001 0.88800000000000001E+000

`lbound(at%mag(:,i))` is 1; `ubound(at%mag(:,i))` is 3;

However, `call print('this is postion==========='//at%mag(1,i))` gives the error Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.  I know the index of this array, why the memory reference is invaild for at%mag(1,i)?     Does there any way to find what is wrong?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please show a [mre]. However, the examples you show are completely different things: one has an array actual argument and one a scalar actual argument. We need to see the subroutine `print` to say more, but it's unlikely to be the array element reference itself that is causing the segmentation fault.

Comment: Note `lbound(at%mag(:,i))` returns the lower bound of the result of the expression `at%mag(:,i)` which is [1] - this says nothing about the bounds of the first dimension of `at%mag` - you want `lbound( at%mag, Dim = 1 )` and similarly for ubound

Comment: This is in a big program with lots of modules, I can not show an reproducible example.   The print function is also too long to post here.  I think it is not because of the print function.  I tried define '''x=at%mag(1,i)''' which also give the same error (x is scalar).  But I can assign  '''y=at%mag(:,i)''' (y is dimension(3)).  again when I use y(1), the same error appears. So weird.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I did use lbound(at%mag(:,i),1) and ubound(at%mag(:,i),1).  So this is not the problem.

Comment: No, that is different - you want `lbound(at%mag,1)` as you want the lower bound of the array  `at%mag` *not* the lower bound of the array valued expression `at%mag(:,i)`. They are different, and by the standard the value of the second is definitely 1, but the first *might* be different.

Comment: You are also compiling and running with array bounds checking turned on?

Comment: I  checked the lbound(at%mag,1) and ubound(at%mag,1), they are 1 and 3.  This is not the issue.

Comment: real(dp), pointer, dimension(:,:) :: mag   => null()     mag is defined under the type at.  at%mag is pointer. could this be the reason?

Comment: Even if you can't give a complete example, there is _nothing_ useful we can say if we don't know about the `print` subroutine. Unless `print` is a generic, you can't even use it like you have in these two different ways, and there's infinite scope for segmentation faults within the subroutine (there's no evidence here that the fault is outside the subroutine).

Comment: If `mag` is a real data object, why would the string concatenation `'this is postion==========='//at%mag(:,i)` be expected to work?

Comment: Maybe at%mag(:,i) is a type that has overloaded the // operator but at%mag(1,i) is just a number?